Understanding dielectrics on the basis of induced charge and energy density
Simply, why is the energy density in a dielectric medium = $\frac{1}{2} K \epsilon_o E^2$?
For a simple case such as that of a capacitor with a dielectric medium inside it, to find the magnitude of induced charge, the net electric field can viewed as: $\vec{\text{E}}_{\text{net}} = \vec{\text{E}}_{\text{o}} + \vec{\text{E}}_{\text{p}}$
where $\vec{\text{E}}_{\text{o}}$ is the electric field due to charges on the capacitor plate, and $\vec{\text{E}}_{\text{p}}$ is the electric field due to the oppositely induced charges on the surface of the dielectric.
Further, this can be written as $E_{\text{net}} = E_{\text{o}} - E_{\text{p}}$.
Also, by the definition of a dielectric: $\vec{\text{E}}_{\text{net}} = \frac{\vec{\text{E}}_{\text{o}}}{K}$
the previous two equations imply $E_{\text{p}} = E_{\text{o}}(1-\frac{1}{K})$
Since $E_{\text{o}} = \frac{Q}{A\epsilon_o}$ and $E_{\text{p}} = \frac{Q_p}{A\epsilon_o}$, where $Q$ is the charge on capacitor plate and $Q_p$ is the induced charge, we can imply $$Q_p = Q(1-\frac{1}{K})$$
$E_{\text{p}} = \frac{Q_p}{A\epsilon_o}$, as used above, actually means we have substituted the dielectric medium with two plates of $Q_p$ and $-Q_p$ charge at the two surfaces of the dielectric. This is why the denominator shows $\epsilon_o$ rather than  $K\epsilon_o$.
Now my question is, why can't the energy density be evaluated following this logic of substituting a dielectric with two plates of induced charge?
If I do so, $energy density = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_oE_{\text{net}}^2$ and not $\frac{1}{2}K\epsilon_oE_{\text{net}}^2$, so what is the fundamental difference between two plates holding charge $Q_p$ & $-Q_p$, and a dielectric medium? I imagined a dielectric is just a medium that can produce two plates of opposite charge of a magnitude that is related very specifically to the field it is subjected to.
The proof for $\frac{1}{2}K\epsilon_oE_{\text{net}}^2$ given in Dr. HC Verma's, Concepts of Physics is using a capacitor with dielectric K, which will have energy = $\frac{1}{2}CV^2$, where C is $\frac{K\epsilon_oA}{d}$. (The proof for $\frac{1}{2}CV^2$ was calculating work done in pulling apart two oppositely charged plates from zero separation to separation = d.)
$$u = \frac{U}{Ad} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{K\epsilon_oA}{d}V^2}{Ad} = \frac{1}{2}K\epsilon_oE_{\text{net}}^2$$
To conclude, my question is, why can we view a dielectric as plates of opposite charge for the calculation of field, but not for the calculation of energy density? Besides, I have always learned $\int\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_oE_{\text{net}}^2*dV$ includes all potential energy which manifests in the form of interaction energy, self-energy, etc. If we have already considered the contribution of the dielectric in the net field, why again must we multiply $\epsilon_o$ with K? However, intuitively it does feel correct that making a field in a dielectric would require more energy than making the same field in air.
Answered here

$\dots$ why can we view a dielectric as plates of opposite charge for the calculation of field, but not for the calculation of energy density? because you are considering two different aspects of the situation.
When it comes to evaluating the net electric field within the dielectric one needs to consider the external electric field causing the polarisation of the medium and the electric field caused by the polarisation of the medium.
The electric field caused by the polarisation of the medium can be evaluated by just considering the surface charge densities on the dielectric as the net contribution to the electric field due to the rest of the dielectric is zero.
In terms of energy it is the separation of all the charges, all the molecular dipole moments, within the dielectric which is important not just the separation of the charges at the surface of the dielectric.

why wouldn't $\int\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_oE_{\text{net}}^2dV$ take the internal dipoles into account? for example, if I bring multiple artificial dipoles and place them in otherwise empty space in a particular configuration, $\int\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_oE_{\text{net}}^2dV$ gives the correct total energy. Isn't a dielectric medium just this? the only difference is that an actual dielectric medium would have dipoles much more closely packed.

The point is, if I'm not correct in taking the dielectric as just two plates, I can still take it to be many many dipoles put together, in which case the integral without K should work.. right?
